3SUM Reduction to Distinct Pairwise Sum
The 3SUM problem is defined as follows:
Given three sets of integers $A,B,C \subseteq \{-W,\ldots,W\}$ for $W = n^3$, each containing $n$
integers, determine whether there exsists some $a \in A, b \in B, c \in C$ such that $a+b+c=0$.
(or any equivalent formulation of the problem, e.g., where $a+b=c$.)
The X+Y problem is defined as follows:
Given two sets of integers $X$ and $Y$ , each containing $n$
integers, determine whether the sumset $X + Y = \{a + b \ | \ a \in X, b \in Y \}$ (duplicates allowed) contains $n^2$ distinct integers.
I want to show that this problem is $3SUM$-hard, that is, if the $X+Y$ problem can be solved in $O(n^{2-\epsilon})$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ then $3SUM$ can also be solved in $O(n^{2-\delta})$ for some $\delta > 0$. In particular, I want to show this by reducing the $3SUM$ problem to the $X+Y$ problem. However, I am not able to come up with a sophisticated solution. Any advice would be appreciated.

Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/170015/755, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/54739/5038, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4983946/14578.  Please do not post the same question on multiple sites.
